# Android stock launcher, should i change packet signature

Tags: android, package, android-launcher

i am developing custom launcher based on the stock Android launcher(Launcher 3). My question is: should i change the java package signature (package com.android.launcher3) to the package used by the manufacturer of the tablet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change it but not to the manufacturer's package name. It should use a domain you own in reverse order. *android.com* belongs to Google and the domain used by the manufacturer belongs to that manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended is to use your own package name (organisation, company, ...)

For instance:
my.company.launcher